# search query doesn't work on individual post pages - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search

From the main page and category page, my search form works just fine.  Try to search for "post".

http://blog.papermusepress.com

It will bring up the results.

but if you try to do a search from within an individual post, it doesn't do the search.

try here: http://blog.papermusepress.com/my-second-post/ and search for post, it doesn't do the actual search

anybody have an idea why it would do this?

/single.php/

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="primary">
                <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="post-item">
                    <div class="title-tape">
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <p class="meta">Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> on <?php the_date(); ?></p>
                    </div><!-- end title-tape -->
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div><!-- end post-item -->

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <p>We aren't sure what you are looking for..</p>                
                <?php endif; ?>

                <div id="comments_template">
                    <?php comments_template(); ?>
                </div><!-- end comments_template -->



            </div> <!-- end primary -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- end main -->
    </div><!-- end wrap -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Could you post the code from your single.php (or whatever template you are using for individual posts) file?

Comment: there you go!  in main post now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the search query string is being appended to the full URL each time when it should only be added to the root URL. For example, if you are on  http://blog.papermusepress.com/my-second-post/ the search is added to the end of that URL (instead of just http://blog.papermusepress.com/) which only allows that current page to be searched. This will keep the current template and bypass the search results page.

Check the form action in your searchform.php file. The opening form tag should look something like this:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
```

If your form has an empty action, `action=""` , it will post back to itself. This can be useful, but is definitely not what you want for wordpress search.

Comment: thank you so much.  that is what it was.  replaced with your php and it worked.